# Two for loops one ascending one descending creates two different data structures

Tags: javascript

I have an array that I am looping twice, one im looping from pointer 0 and up and the other im looping backwards.

But they produce different array layouts in console.log which i find strange .. this is what i have:

```
//array has a length of 3 [0,1,2]
var data = [],
    data2 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++){
 data[i] = {};
 data[i].test = 'Hello';
}
for(var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
 data2[i] = {};
 data2[i].test = 'Hello';
}
console.log(data);
console.log(data2);
```

Now in my console log they come out different like this:

[image]

So why does the second one have a length of 3 but only 2 objects? And why does the second console.log have numbers in front of the objects unlike the first one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `length` of an `Array` is simply the `max(index) + 1`.

When you create a "*sparse*" array, the intermediate indexes are still treated as existing.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data2));
// [null, {"test":"Hello"}, {"test":"Hello"}]
```

Even if the instance doesn't itself have them.

```
console.log('0' in data2);
// false
```

---

If you want a count of keys that were used, you could get the `length` of its [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
console.log(Object.keys(data2).length);
// 2
```

Possibly [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to just indexes.

```
Object.indexes = function (target) {
    return Object.keys(target).filter(function (key) {
        return key === String(parseInt(key, 10));
    });
};

console.log(Object.indexes(data2).length);
```

Note that these snippets expect an [ES5-based engine](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) or polyfills.

Comment: Ah ok! I might as well set the data's to objects then from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop has this continuing condition:

```
i > 0
```

Which stops it before it gets to the data2[0] position.

And so, you're setting data2[2] and then data2[1]. data2[0] remains unset but it's still in the array (it's still the pointer position).

This is what you're looking for

```
for(var i = array.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
 data2[i] = {};
 data2[i].test = 'Hello';
}
```

Comment: I know because i only want it to loop twice.